# Why is my GPU's red led on?

Tags: gpu

My GPU is an AMD Rx 570 XFX 4GB.

I was playing Doom 4 (2016) and it crashed.
I checked my GPU and in addition to the blue LED that is always on, a red LED had turned on.

What does it mean?

What could have caused this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally I'd say "Check the manual" - but there's no manual on their webpage. Their [troubleshooting page however says](https://helpdesk.xfxforce.com/hc/en-us/articles/360049662213-Blue-or-Red-light-near-the-PCI-E-Power-Connections-What-they-Mean)

> Blue Light = Power is connected properly, card will have this blue light under normal operation.
>
> Red Light = Indicates an incorrect power connection. Something is wrong with the way the card is connected with the power supply, the video card will not produce video signal until this is resolved.

Considering you were gaming - I'd guess the PSU couldn't deal with increased power draw on a 12V rail (Many PSUs split them, so other devices might work correctly, even if 'one' rail is overloaded). If it works correctly under normal circumstances, a more 'involved' benchmark might trigger off the same issues, and it might be useful if you can monitor power draw with something like GPU-Z when trying to replicate the issue to confirm.